# Significance of comma ',' operator, for concatenating strings in Unix

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

```
$ ls -ltr  /{,usr/}bin/l*|tail -4
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        31544 Dec 20  2017 /usr/bin/login
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        31544 Dec 20  2017 /bin/login
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug 28  2018 /usr/bin/libpng-config -> libpng12-config
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug 28  2018 /bin/libpng-config -> libpng12-config
```

This gives name of all executable files that starts with letter `l` in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` directory.

If I paly with `,` by changing its position I get results that I don't understand. For e.g., refer screenshot below.

```
$ ls -ltr  /{,usr,/}bin/l*|tail -4
/usrbin/l*: No such file or directory
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        31544 Dec 20  2017 /bin/login
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        31544 Dec 20  2017 //bin/login
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug 28  2018 /bin/libpng-config -> libpng12-config
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug 28  2018 //bin/libpng-config -> libpng12-config
```

Same as above (order of list has changed) but `usr` is missing.

```
$ ls -ltr  /{usr,/}bin/l*|tail -4
/usrbin/l*: No such file or directory
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     other       2286 Jun 15  2017 //bin/libpng14-config
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        28608 Oct 20  2017 //bin/ldaplist
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root     bin        31544 Dec 20  2017 //bin/login
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          15 Aug 28  2018 //bin/libpng-config -> libpng12-config
```

This is the files present only in /bin with extra `/` as prefix with every entry.

Please explain what kind charm is being performed by `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces are replaced by each of the strings between the commas, so
`X{,a,b}Y` is expanded to `XY XaY XbY`, so your `/{usr,/}bin/l` is expanded to `/usrbin/l* /bin/l*`, and not `/usr/bin/l*` as you seem to expect.

```
/{,usr/}bin/l*  #-> /[]bin/l* /[usr/]bin/l*
/{,usr,/}bin/l* #-> /[]bin/l* /[usr]bin/l* /[/]bin/l*
/{usr,/}bin/l*  #-> /[usr]bin/l* /[/]bin/l*
```